# How to get all managers from EMP and DEPT table per deptno (10, 20, 30)?

Tags: sql, oracle

From the table EMP and DEPT I want to get all employees that are managers of departments, grouped by deptno:
 ( eg. 10  KING, CLARK, 20 KING, JONES, SCOTT,FORD..., 30 BLAKE, KING ..)
In this table exists " mgr" that means "managers", so for example : CLARK works in department number 10, his mgr is 7839, which is empno of KING. That means " KING is one of the menagers in the department 10" . My question is how to write a query that will return a result of all menagers that works in departments 10, 20, 30 ? How to join mgr and empno?

```
DEPTNO DNAME               EMPNO ENAME
```

---

```
    10 ACCOUNTING           7782 CLARK     
    10 ACCOUNTING           7839 KING      
    10 ACCOUNTING           7934 MILLER    
    20 RESEARCH             7566 JONES     
    20 RESEARCH             7902 FORD      
    20 RESEARCH             7876 ADAMS     
    20 RESEARCH             7369 SMITH     
    20 RESEARCH             7788 SCOTT     
    30 SALES                7521 WARD      
    30 SALES                7844 TURNER    
    30 SALES                7499 ALLEN     
    30 SALES                7900 JAMES     
    30 SALES                7698 BLAKE     
    30 SALES                7654 MARTIN  

insert into emp values (7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', 7902, to_date('17-DEC-80'), 800, NULL, 20); 
insert into emp values (7499, 'ALLEN', 'SALESMAN', 7698, to_date('20-FEB-81'), 1600, 300, 30);
insert into emp values (7521, 'WARD', 'SALESMAN', 7698, to_date('22-FEB-81'), 1250, 500, 30); 
insert into emp values (7566, 'JONES', 'MANAGER', 7839, to_date('02-APR-81'), 2975, NULL, 20); 
insert into emp values (7654, 'MARTIN','SALESMAN', 7698, to_date('28-SEP-81'), 1250, 1400, 30);
insert into emp values (7698, 'BLAKE', 'MANAGER', 7839, to_date('01-MAY-81'), 2850, NULL, 30); 
insert into emp values (7782, 'CLARK', 'MANAGER', 7839, to_date('09-JUN-81'), 2450, NULL, 10); 
insert into emp values (7788, 'SCOTT', 'ANALYST', 7566, to_date('19-APR-87'), 3000, NULL, 20); 
insert into emp values (7839, 'KING', 'PRESIDENT', NULL, to_date('17-NOV-81'), 5000, NULL, 10);
insert into emp values (7844, 'TURNER','SALESMAN', 7698, to_date('08-SEP-81'), 1500, 0, 30);
insert into emp values (7876, 'ADAMS', 'CLERK', 7788, to_date('23-MAY-87'), 1100, NULL, 20);
insert into emp values (7900, 'JAMES', 'CLERK', 7698, to_date('03-DEC-81'), 950, NULL, 30);
insert into emp values (7902, 'FORD', 'ANALYST', 7566, to_date('03-DEC-81'), 3000, NULL, 20); 
insert into emp values (7934, 'MILLER','CLERK', 7782, to_date('23-JAN-82'), 1300, NULL, 10);
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK'); 
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (20, 'RESEARCH', 'DALLAS');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (30, 'SALES', 'CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (40, 'OPERATIONS', 'BOSTON');
```

Expected result must be (d.deptno, d.dname, e.empno, e.ename): for deptno 10 (KING, CLARK), deptno 20(KING, JONES, SCOTT, FORD) and for deptno 30 (BLAKE, KING).

Comment: How does your data convey that KING is the manager for CLARK?

Comment: How do you tell which departments people work in?

Comment: For example, in the first row in the department 10 is CLARK, with empno 7782. Later, in the department 10 is also MILLER, and if you look at mgr there is 7782, that means CLARK is the manager of MILLER in the department 10. In this query I wanted to get all managers that exists in the department 10, department 20 and department 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, and in the future try to explain better with table structure, input and expected output, then this is what you need:

```
SELECT d.depNO,d.DNAME,e.EMPNO,e.ENAME
FROM EMP e
INNER JOIN dept d
ON(e.depno = d.depno)
WHERE EXISTS(select 1 from EMP t where t.mgr = e.empNO)
AND d.depNO in(10,20,30)
```

This will join the tables together, filter only departments 10 20 and 30, and check if for that employee exists another employee that he is the manager of.

EDIT: if what you want is to go drill down, and if king a manager on people on all departments that he should appear on each one, then this is what you need:

```
SELECT distinct d.depNO,d.DNAME,e2.EMPNO,e2.ENAME
FROM EMP e
INNER JOIN dept d
ON(e.depno = d.depno)
INNER JOIN EMP e2
ON e2.EMPNO = e.mgr
where d.depNO in(10,20,30)
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, in the future I will try to explain better. Yes, this is what I  try to find, but the query doesn't show all the managers. If in the department 10 employees KING and CLARK are managers of that department, there in the  department 20 is listed just JONES, SCOTT and FORD, not KING.  The same problem is in the department 30, there is just BLAKE, and not BLAKE and KING . Can you help me with that?

Comment: I updated something, but I'm new in that.  My inputs are table EMP (empno, ename, mgr), DEPT (dept, dname) and I want to get deptno and dname from DEPT and empno, ename from EMP of the managers(mgr) who works there. Sorry if I don't know to explain, I have a problem with the language :/

Comment: OK, i edited all inputs above (ename : clark, miller, king, jones, ford, adams, smith, scott, ward, turner, allen, james, blake, martin ), (mgr : king, clark, /, king, jones, scott, ford, jones, blake, blake, blake, blake, king, blake) and the output is dept 10= king, clark, dept 20= king, jones, scott, ford and dept 30= blake, king .. or other words, I want deptno, dname, empno, ename.  Sorry if I was wrong again

Comment: the query shows wrong records.. Now the output  dept 10= Jones, Blake, Clark, Miller, what is not true, the managers of dept 10 are just King and Clark.. Your first query was almost good, there was missing just the employee who has already been named early in the another department. (EG. in the department 10 Clark and King are managers of the department 10, and later in the department 20 and 30, employee king is missing. In the department is listed Jones, Scott, Ford and there is missing King who is also manager of the department 10, 20 and 30. )

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, confused the join condition... do it now it will work.. @GoranBartBartolić

Comment: It works !!!! thanks you a lot, your query returns all managers from deptno 10, 20 30 :))

Comment: Just you have to change "depno " with "depTno" ..everything alse is perfect ! Thanks :)